# Aggregation Pipeline Count Sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a problem with aggregation. I can not or do not understand how to build it. This is my collection:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("5b900efbb9440c000646f803"),
"status": 0,
"date": NumberLong(0),
"player1": {
    "name": "",
    "sets": [{
        "points": [{
            "score": 0,
            "comment": "sa"
        }, {
            "score": 1,
            "comment": "sw"
        }, {
            "score": 2,
            "comment": "sw"
        }]
    }]
},
"player2": {
    "name": "",
    "sets": [{
        "points": [{
            "score": 0,
            "comment": ""
        }, {
            "score": 1,
            "comment": "fh"
        }, {
            "score": 2,
            "comment": "sw"
        }]
    }]
}}
```

How I can count sum of points for player1 where comment is "sw"?

Thanks. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

Use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to filter points where comment = 'sw' followed by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to count matches in each point array. Use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to perform the logic for all sets and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to calculate the all matches across all sets

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"player1.name":"","player2.name":""}},
  {"$project":{
    "count":{
      "$add":[
        {"$sum":{
          "$map":{
            "input":"$player1.sets",
            "as":"set",
            "in":{
              "$size":{
                "$filter":{"input":"$$set.points","cond":{"$eq":["$$this.comment","sw"]}}
              }
            }
          }
        }},
        {"$sum":{
          "$map":{
            "input":"$player2.sets",
            "as":"set",
            "in":{
              "$size":{
                "$filter":{"input":"$$set.points","cond":{"$eq":["$$this.comment","sw"]}}
              }
            }
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the trick:

```
db.colname.aggregate(
{
    { $unwind: "$player1.sets" },
    { $unwind: "$player1.sets.points" },
    { $match: { player1.sets.points.comment: "sw" },
    {
        $group : {
           _id : null,
           total: { $sum: $player1.sets.points.comment },
        }
    }
})
```